# Google Custom Search - Synonyms linked to Annotations labels

Tags: search, google-search-appliance

I'm trying to figure out how I can use Synonyms to only search against specific sites in the Annotations via the label - but can't find any information on how to do this.

Can you have Synonyms setup / linked to only search specific sites via labels? or how can you call the API to use a specific Synonym and pass which label to use and thus only search those sites that correspond to the label?

Any help / advice would be very much appreciated

Just to add we are using the Google Search API to fire off the searches and then return results programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure out how this should be done

Setup refinements and associated labels
Associate these to your annotations
Setup your Synonyms

You can now call your Synonyms and use the more: option to select the label you want use